# How to reverse Euler rotation?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

I have a vector v=$\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3 \end{pmatrix}$ which I will rotate using Euler rotation. After I tested some vectors and some rotations I found out that to reverse a Euler rotation you have invert the rotation order and then rotate by the negative amount of rotation in each axis.

So if I have a vector v=$\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3 \end{pmatrix}$ which I first rotate by $r_1$ around the x-axis then by $r_2$ around the y-axis then $r_3$ around the z-axis. To get my original vector v again I have to first rotate by $-r_3$ around the z-axis then by $-r_2$ around the y-axis then $-r_1$ around the x-axis.

I tried to search for proofs of this online however everything I found was proved using matrices, which I unfortunately am not acquainted with.

How can you prove that to reverse a Euler rotation you have to invert the rotation order and then rotate by the negative amount of rotation in each axis without using matrices?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a general property of functions (notice that your rotations are just functions acting in your vectors), namely that the inverse of $f\circ g$ is $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$. If this notation is not familiar to you, it means that if

$$y=f(g(x)),$$

then

$$x=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(y)).$$

To see why, simply notice that

$$g^{-1}(f^{-1}(y))=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(f(g(x))))=g^{-1}(g(x))=x,$$

which can also be written as

\begin{align*}
(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ g)&=g^{-1}\circ(f^{-1}\circ f)\circ g\\
&=g^{-1}\circ\mathrm{Id}\circ g \\
&=g^{-1}\circ g\\
&=\mathrm{Id},
\end{align*}

and similarly for the other direction. Note that this also of course requires invertibility of $f$ and $g$, and in your case, with rotations, clearly they are invertible (you can always just revert a rotation by rotating back).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $f^{-1} (y)$ is it the same as ${1\over f(y)}$?

Comment: No, $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$